# How to use Abstract Class in C#

Tags: c#, abstract-class, abstract

I have a API and it use a abstract class.

I not familiar with abstract class and I also researched about it.

So far this is my code:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Questions_Base
{
 public void Import(Oasis OasisSource);
}
```

---

```
  public class Questions : Questions_Base
   {
            public  Questions()
            {
                //
                // TODO: Add constructor logic here
                //
                }


    public void Import(Oasis OasisSource) {

        string B1String;
        while ((B1String = OasisFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Questions oQuestions = new Questions();
            Oasis oOasis = new Oasis();
            oOasis.B1 = B1String;
            oQuestions.Import(oOasis); //error here Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         }
      }
}
```

Please Advice me.. thanks!

Comment: Why does your title have a different error message than your code example?

Comment: @kirk, I already modified it. sorry. thanks

Comment: Most likely the exception is being raised in `.Import`.  Please edit your question to include the **full** stack trace.

Comment: your code, as is, shouldn't compile

Comment: It's likely that something inside of Import is throwing that error. The "abstract" part of the class is not really relevant to the discussion here other than to show that Questions_Base likely implements a buggy Import method.

Comment: ok guys. I'll modified it and complete my codes

Comment: Your code sample won't compile.  For starters, the Questions_Base class contains a method (Import) that has no implementation, but isn't marked abstract.  Either that method needs an implementation, or it need to be marked abstract, and then overriden in the Questions class.

Comment: I think this is just the class meta-data for Questions_Base.

Comment: @Margarrete, you still haven't shown the stack trace.

Comment: Hmm.. What I suppose to do with this?

Comment: @kirk,i don't what is the stack trace.. XD

Comment: @ShyGuy +1 - We're on the same page.

Comment: Your Import method appears to be calling the Questions.Import method recursively (instantiating a new class of Questions and calling Import again). This is just a shot in the dark, but try calling base.Import(oOasis); instead of oQuestions.oOasis (you don't even need to instantiate oQuestions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abstract classes are used to provide common functionality to child classes and force child to have own implementation of abstract members. it cannot be initialized, so individually it is not an object, but takes part in behaviour of child class

Comment: This is not the problem. The inheritance and instantiation is done properly. The issue is that the method in the abstract class is not marked abstract and not overridden in the child class.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct - you cannot create an instance of an abstract class. You need to define an class that inherits from your abstract class, and create the objects of this.

An abstract class is only for inheriting from. Nothing else.

Basically.

Comment: I did say basically. I am not dismissing the importance of them, but they are not for instantiating. I tried to express it more in the first para

Answer (score 1):

First up:

```
public void Import(Oasis OasisSource);
```

Should be

```
public abstract void Import(Oasis OasisSource);
```

If you want all children of this abstract class to implement there own `Import` functionality, otherwise implement the functionality in the base abstract class, mark it as virtual so the children can override if necessary.

The error is because you have not implemented this function correctly.

Comment: I can't modify it because this is a dll

Comment: Aha! you are reading the code that is displayed from meta data! I agree with @ShyGuy

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is caused by something in the body of the Questions.Import method.  Which you have not provided us.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract modifier can be used with classes, methods, properties, indexers, and events.